# Difference between SQL IN and OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL & I got confused with the below queries.

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE (studentId=1 OR studentId=2);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE studentId IN (1,2);
```

I see the same results for both. Technically Can I use any of them?

Comment: Yes. In SQL there are generally more than one way to get the same result.

Comment: "The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions." Hence, you can use either of them.